# Find max of arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I am using the data below in my ArrayList:

[image]

I am wondering how to get the maximum percentage of marketName in pair similar below

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Basically you want got each marketName the entries should be sorted based on percent right, like Liqui has three entries , so percent 0.52 should come first, then 0.59, then 0.65 and then 0.73. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: Also please share your code with us, so that we can understand what have you tried so far.

Comment: In ETH/BTC pair, find max of Bitrex, Liqui, Yobit. In LTC/BTC pair find max of Bitrex, Liqui, Yobit. I have't written code yet.

Comment: Got it... I can write something and give you but to make things simple, I will hardcode this above data in an array for now but in your case you will be parsing this from the above excel file ..

Answer (score 1):

Following is the logic :

1. Create a TreeMap which will keep keys sorted according to pair .
2. Use combination of pair and marcketName as key and

   1. if that key does not exist put it into Map
   2. else Check with stored value if current value is larger replace 
      with larger.
3. Loop Through TreeMap and print the result required.

   ```
   public class FindMaxArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<Marcket> marcketList=new ArrayList<>();
       Map<String,Double> maxofArrayList=new TreeMap<>();

       // Create Sample Data
       Marcket m1=new Marcket("BitTrex", "ETH/BTC",0.518);marcketList.add(m1);
       Marcket m2=new Marcket("Liqui", "ETH/BTC",0.658);marcketList.add(m2);
       Marcket m3=new Marcket("Yobit", "ETH/BTC",0.658);marcketList.add(m3);
       Marcket m4=new Marcket("BitTrex", "ETH/BTC",0.618);marcketList.add(m4);
       Marcket m5=new Marcket("Liqui", "ETH/BTC",0.458);marcketList.add(m5);
       Marcket m6=new Marcket("Yobit", "ETH/BTC",0.758);marcketList.add(m6);


       Marcket m11=new Marcket("BitTrex", "LTC/BTC",0.818);marcketList.add(m11);
       Marcket m12=new Marcket("Liqui", "LTC/BTC",0.458);marcketList.add(m12);
       Marcket m13=new Marcket("Yobit", "LTC/BTC",0.758);marcketList.add(m13);
       Marcket m14=new Marcket("BitTrex", "LTC/BTC",0.518);marcketList.add(m14);
       Marcket m15=new Marcket("Liqui", "LTC/BTC",0.858);marcketList.add(m15);
       Marcket m16=new Marcket("Yobit", "LTC/BTC",0.958);marcketList.add(m16);


       //Processing List 
       for(Marcket m:marcketList) {
           if(maxofArrayList.containsKey(m.getPair()+":"+m.getMarcketName())) {
               if(maxofArrayList.get(m.getPair()+":"+m.getMarcketName())<m.getPercentage()){
                   maxofArrayList.put(m.getPair()+":"+m.getMarcketName(), m.getPercentage());
               }
           }else {
               maxofArrayList.put(m.getPair()+":"+m.getMarcketName(), m.getPercentage());
           }
       }

       //Printing List
       for(String key:maxofArrayList.keySet()) {
           String[] content=key.split(":");
           System.out.println(content[1]+"\t"+content[0]+"\t"+maxofArrayList.get(key));
       }
   }
   }

   class Marcket{

   private String marcketName;
   private String pair;
   private double percentage;

   public Marcket(String marcketName, String pair, double percentage) {
       this.marcketName = marcketName;
       this.pair = pair;
       this.percentage = percentage;
   }
   public String getMarcketName() {
       return marcketName;
   }
   public void setMarcketName(String marcketName) {
       this.marcketName = marcketName;
   }
   public String getPair() {
       return pair;
   }
   public void setPair(String pair) {
       this.pair = pair;
   }
   public double getPercentage() {
       return percentage;
   }
   public void setPercentage(float percentage) {
       this.percentage = percentage;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please 1) explain your solution and why it works rather than just dumping code, and 2) format your code properly.